# Cannot resolve method setImageBitmap using custom view

Tags: android

I want to download the image from the url and display it in my custom view. I am unable to resolve the setImageBitmap method. How can i display image from a url into custom imageview? The name of my custom view is MemeEditorView.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.dragedy.dream.view.MemeEditorView;

import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Created by Jai Mahlawat on 3/12/2017.
 */

class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    MemeEditorView memeEditorView;

    public ImageDownloader(MemeEditorView memeEditorView) {
        this.memeEditorView = memeEditorView;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String url = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
            mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return mIcon;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        memeEditorView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `MemeEditorView extends ImageView`?

Comment: @MikeM.it extends view

Comment: `View` does not have a `setImageBitmap()` method. Either implement that yourself, or just extend `ImageView` instead, if you need the image scaling the `ImageView` provides.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries like [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) and [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) make it easy to accomplish what you want to do.

For example, using Picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("//**Your URL Here**//").into(MemeEditorView);
```

Using Picasso and Glide also helps in caching, cropping, resizing and other images features.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that MemeEditorView extends ImageView, otherwise you probably need to use [setBackground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) method.